# Do we still need to write plus or minus when solving this equation including a square root?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, education

When solving an example like the attached picture, we say x is +/- answer.

[image]

But if the equation is $$x+4=\sqrt{9/16}$$ 
Are we supposed to write plus or minus in this case too?

Comment: Writing $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm \sqrt 4$ in the image is not quite right -- the $\sqrt{\phantom 4}$ notation always means the _positive_ square root, and applying the $\sqrt{\phantom 4}$ function on both sides of the equation $x^2=4$ cannot suddenly make a minus appear out of nowhere. In the _next_ step, $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt 4$ should have been rewritten to $|x|=\sqrt 4$ which is the same as $x=\pm 2$.

Comment: If you had $(x+4)^2=9/16$ then yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 2):

No. $\sqrt{\frac9{16}}$ is just the non-negative real number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2=\frac9{16}$, and that's *why* the solution to $x^2=4$ is $x=\pm\sqrt4$. The expression $x+4=\sqrt{\frac9{16}}$ just means $x+4=\frac34$.